# How to get a colored base using boost gil

Tags: c++, boost, gil

How can I get image color base is RGB, RGBA or gray?

My code:

```
int main() {

 using namespace boost::gil;
 typedef boost::mpl::vector<gray8_image_t, rgb8_image_t, gray16_image_t, rgb16_image_t> my_images_t;

 any_image<my_images_t> dynamic_img;
 jpeg_read_image("test.jpg",dynamic_img);



 return 0;
}
```

Comment: Please avoid duplicate questions

Comment: I Did not find the same problem XD